# What is the difference between ProxyFactory and ProxyFactoryBean in Spring Framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I have the following sample code:

**MyMethodBeforeAdviceImpl.java**

```
import org.springframework.aop.MethodBeforeAdvice;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class MyMethodBeforeAdviceImpl implements MethodBeforeAdvice {
    @Override
    public void before(Method method, Object[] args, Object target) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("MyMethodBeforeAdviceImpl#before");
    }
}
```

**MyService.java**

```
public interface MyService {
    void serve();
}
```

**MyServiceImpl.java**

```
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    @Override
    public void serve() {
        System.out.println("MyServiceImpl#serve");
    }
}
```

and finally **App.java**

```
import org.springframework.aop.MethodBeforeAdvice;
import org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory;
import org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final MyServiceImpl myService = new MyServiceImpl();
        final MethodBeforeAdvice myMethodBeforeAdvice = new MyMethodBeforeAdviceImpl();

        final ProxyFactory proxyFactory = new ProxyFactory();
        proxyFactory.addAdvice(myMethodBeforeAdvice);
        proxyFactory.setTarget(myService);

        MyService proxyServiceFromFactory = (MyService) proxyFactory.getProxy();
        proxyServiceFromFactory.serve();

        final ProxyFactoryBean proxyFactoryBean = new ProxyFactoryBean();
        proxyFactoryBean.addAdvice(myMethodBeforeAdvice);
        proxyFactoryBean.setTarget(myService);

        MyService proxyServiceFromFactoryBean = (MyService) proxyFactoryBean.getObject();
        proxyServiceFromFactoryBean.serve();

        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

The output of the main method will be:

```
MyMethodBeforeAdviceImpl#before
MyServiceImpl#serve
MyMethodBeforeAdviceImpl#before
MyServiceImpl#serve
```

So as far as for this very small example, they exactly serve the same purpose. The [ProxyFactory documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/framework/ProxyFactory.html) states:

> Factory for AOP proxies for programmatic use, rather than via
>   declarative setup in a bean factory. This class provides a simple way
>   of obtaining and configuring AOP proxy instances in custom user code.

But it seems to me like you may as well use ProxyFactoryBean for the same purpose?

How do these 2 classes serve different purposes?

Comment: `ProxyFactoryBean` is essentially the same thing as `ProxyFactory` (they have the same superclass). It just additionally implements `FactoryBean` so Spring can control its lifecycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ProxyFactory is independently of Spring's IoC container.
ProxyFactoryBean is combining Spring AOP with Spring's IoC container.